# How to make permit template responsive in mobile

Tags: responsive

Could anyone please guide me on how to make the PowerApps portal responsive on mobile?

The PowerApps portal layout doesn't look good in the mobile browser for the permit template. Especially the header links are not in the correct place.

Any ideas?